# How do I add /UF command to a pdf using pdfbox?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, pdfbox, pspdfkit

I have implemented functionality to add a relative link into a pdf using the pdfbox library.Below is the code that I am using for adding the link:

```
 PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
 PDActionRemoteGoTo remoteGoto = new PDActionRemoteGoTo();
 PDComplexFileSpecification fileDesc = new PDComplexFileSpecification();
 fileDesc.setFile(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
 remoteGoto.setOpenInNewWindow(true);
 remoteGoto.setFile(fileDesc);
 txtLink.setAction(remoteGoto);
 txtLink.setRectangle(rect);
 page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
```

Here is the command entered in the pdf:

```
14 0 obj
<<
/Type /Filespec
/F (A-201-NORTH & SOUTHSITE ELEVATIONS.pdf)
>>
endobj
```

The links work in adobe, ios viewer. But does not work in PSPDF. Also, I have file whose link work in PSPDF. But the commands in that file differ slightly from the  above.Here is the link command that works in the PSPDF:

```
113 0 obj
<<
/Type /Filespec
/F (A8.1 - INTERIOR ELEVATION.pdf)
/UF (A8.1 - INTERIOR ELEVATION.pdf)
/Desc()
>>
```

So, how do I create this command using pdfbox.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in PSPDFKit 7.0.3 for iOS. Thanks for reporting! https://pspdfkit.com/changelog/ios/#7.0.3  (#12884). If you have further issues, feel free to ping us on https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/ - your license subscription includes support and the team is happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the /UF entry, use `setFileUnicode(String file)`.

To add the /Desc entry, use `setFileDescription(String description)`.

I'm also including the answer by Rad, which is rather a comment and may be deleted:

> If you believe there's an issue in PSPDFKit, please open a support request [here](https://pspdfkit.com/support/request). We'd love to help!